# dynamically change url in asp.net like facebook and twitter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url, url-rewriting

How can I dynamically change URL in asp.net like facebook and twitter.

Please see image below:

> **Twitter**

[image]

.
.

> **Facebook**

[image]

Comment: You can use `url rewrite` technique in asp.net. [Read more](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net). If you are using MVC, [its much easier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)

Comment: Added. But the edit needs to be accepted.

Comment: @TheUknown many thanks, I have checked url rewrite and tried in demo application. But it dose not work as I am looking for, as like facebook and twitter. You can see I have marked the pointer in images to explain my requirements.

Comment: You should then post your code and output and any errors that you face.

Comment: I don't know that, why some one downvote my question. He think that this question is general and its answer is available on google. If he is smart enough then proof me that he is intelligent and google it and provide me the some references on this topic. If can't then remove downvote this question. For your information I would like to inform you that I have made research on this question as I told to @TheUknown. PLEASE READ THE COMMENTS BEFORE MARKDOWN.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net Routing should help you achieve this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [history API](https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/) to dynamically change the URL, and this is done via JavaScript

```
<script>
    history.replaceState(null, null, 'zuck');
</script>
```

This code when called would update the url to http://www.example/zuck. You can also use pushState function as well, which adds the url to the browser history

Comment: thanks for your answer, I had tried your suggestion and got my scenario working for temporarily at least, but I am dealing some difficulty in further scenario.